# Jenkins on Docker - Free Swap Space 0

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

I've noticed that my master node on Jenkins shows

```
free swap space: 0 B
```

So I added a swap file as described [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IOException+Not+enough+space).

But this has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @dknaack, any luck oh finding the reason for this?

Comment: @olyv my container was running in a kubernetes cluster. After giving the deployment more resources, the problem was solved. Good luck and have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will continue investigate issue wtih my jenkins

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command to see if your host has a swap file configured:

```
free|grep -i Swap
Swap:            0          0          0
```

If you get "Swap:            0          0          0" like you see above your host has no swap configured.

Configure a swap file on your host:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=1M count=1K
sudo mkswap swapfile
sudo chown root:root swapfile
sudo chmod 600 swapfile
sudo swapon swapfile
```

Verify your swap is configured:

```
free|grep -i Swap
Swap:      1048572          0    1048572
```

Good, we have a swap on the host.

Run your Jenkins docker by typing:

```
docker run --privileged -p 8080:8080 --name jenkins -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

Notice you must run the docker in privileged mode.

When you run your Jenkins docker in privileged mode the host's swap will be available inside the docker, so your Jenkins master will have a working swap.

If your host already has a working swap in place, all you will need to do is run the Jenkins docker in privileged mode.